# How to read File upload File Name in Alert Box in AngularJS ng-fileupload

Tags: angularjs

HTML Code

```
<input type="file" file-model="vm.myFile" />
<button data-ng-click="vm.uploadFile($files)" ng-file-select ng-file-change="vm.uploadFile($files)">upload me</button>
```

AngularJS Code

```
vm.uploadFile = function ($files) {
alert($files);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`$files` is an array of `files`, you will have to traverse through it, if you have only a single file, you can do `$files[0].name`

Comment: Sorry not working, Could you please re write the code

Comment: do you get anything in $files ? can you create a plunker or fiddle?

Comment: the fiddle needs to have the proper angular code, it won't work

Comment: you haven't linked angular and your angularFileUpload module in the js